# Comparison of Epoch in subselect of Sqlite

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to capture the next row where the timestamp is between ts and nextts. I have columns with ts and nextts in the form of Epoch.

```
id,ts,tsepoch,origin,product,bid,ask,nextts,nexttsepoch
1,2016-10-18  20:20:54.733,1476822054733,sourceA,EUR/USD,1.09812,1.0982,2016-10-18  20:20:59.579,1476822059579
2,2016-10-18  20:20:55.093,1476822055093,sourceA,UK 100,7010.5,7011.5,2016-10-18  20:20:57.972,1476822057972
3,2016-10-18  20:20:55.149,1476822055149,sourceA,US 30,18159.0,18161.0,2016-10-18  20:20:55.871,1476822055871
4,2016-10-18  20:20:55.871,1476822055871,sourceA,US 30,18159.0,18161.0,2016-10-18  20:20:57.256,1476822057256
5,2016-10-18  20:20:57.256,1476822057256,sourceA,US 30,18160.0,18162.0,2016-10-18  20:20:58.745,1476822058745
```

Why is the following query returning null?

```
select _rowid_, ts, nextts, origin, bid, ask, 
(select sub.bid from end as sub where sub.origin <> origin and sub.product = product
and sub.tsepoch > tsepoch and sub.tsepoch < nexttsepoch ) as bid

from test
order by ts;
```

I don't understand why a comparison of the two integer columns is returning nothing. When I just try to return ANY value where the timestamp is larger than the current one, it returns null also.

```
select _rowid_, ts, nextts, origin, bid, ask, 
(select sub.bid from end as sub where sub.ts > ts) as bid

from end where product = "UK 100" 
order by ts;
```

Do I have the right DB structure? ts and nextts are datetime and tsepoch and nexttsepoch are NUMERIC.

Comment: Could you show your schema please? Have you run the subqueries separately and checked what they're doing?

Comment: `ts` and `tsepoch` don't represent the same date and time. Are they supposed to? If not, they could use more descriptive names and should probably use the same type for consistency. If so, they should be folded into one column to avoid data duplication.

Comment: Please note that the format is not "epoch" but "milliseconds since the [epoch](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/epoch)". And SQLite uses seconds instead, so it appears these are Java timestamps.

Comment: @CL Ah ha! Now they line up. I somehow didn't notice the dates were in the year 48768. :) In that case that table has duplicated data.

Comment: I don't understand. 'ts' and 'tsepoch' DO represent the same date and time. 'tsepoch' is seconds since the epoch + milliseconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this subquery.

```
select sub.bid
from end as sub
where sub.origin <> origin  and
      sub.product = product and
      sub.tsepoch > tsepoch and
      sub.tsepoch < nexttsepoch
```

It compares each row with itself. There's no join table involved so `origin` and `sub.origin` are both `end.origin`. It's like writing:

```
select bid
from end
where origin <> origin  and
      product = product and
      tsepoch > tsepoch and
      tsepoch < nexttsepoch
```

Instead you probably need a self-join to compare columns of `end` with other columns of `end`.

```
select end1.bid
from end as end1
join end as end2 on end1.id <> end2.id
where end1.origin <> end2.origin  and
      end1.product = end2.product and
      end1.tsepoch > end2.tsepoch and
      end1.tsepoch < end2.nexttsepoch
```

That returns nothing because they all have the same origin and further issues with the where clause filtering out all the results.

Comment: Nevermind, it's correct. They just all have the same `origin`.

Comment: I can't get the query to return anything. Should I index some of the columns?

Comment: @user2146441 Indexing is about performance. It's your `where` conditions, they're filtering out all the rows. You should start with the subquery, remove the `where` clause to verify it's working, then add `where` conditions one at a time to see its effect. Add `end1.id` and `end2.id` to the columns you're selecting so you can see which columns are being compared.